Do I need to sign the code for automatic updates?
I'm using electron-release-server. In the code:

const server = 'https://release.%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2Aru/'
const url = ${server}/update/win64/0.0.0/stable/RELEASES

autoUpdater.setFeedURL({ url })

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow();

  autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();

  autoUpdater.on('checking-for-update', () => {
    // ...
  });
});

As a result, I get the following error: System.AggregateException: ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
This happens after installing and running the application. The update for version 0.0.0 is uploaded, and a Postman request returns a 200 response.
Do I need to sign the code?
Postman request returns a 200 response.
